# L2VPN xconnect state in IOS-XR routers over SNMP

Tags: snmp, cisco-ios-xr

Is it possible to get L2VPN xconnect state in IOS-XR routers over SNMP? It should have 7 possible states(*Up*, *Down*, *Admin Down*, *Unresolved*, *Standby*, *Standby Ready*, *Partially Programmed*):

```
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:r1#show l2vpn xconnect group TEST-GROUP xc-name TEST-XCONNECT        
Legend: ST = State, UP = Up, DN = Down, AD = Admin Down, UR = Unresolved,
        SB = Standby, SR = Standby Ready, (PP) = Partially Programmed

XConnect                   Segment 1                       Segment 2                
Group      Name       ST   Description            ST       Description            ST    
------------------------   -----------------------------   -----------------------------
TEST-GROUP TEST-XCONNECT
                      UP   Gi0/1/0/1.2            UP       192.0.2.27   2110   UP    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RP/0/RSP0/CPU0:r1#
```

At least for example polling pseudo-wire packet statistics over SNMP in IOS-XR is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CISCO-IETF-PW-MIB::cpwVcTable provides pseudo-wire VC status and some other configuration data.
CISCO-IETF-PW-MIB::cpwVcPerfTotalTable gives per-VC packets and bytes 64-bit counters.

With net-snmp utils you can try queries like (works on ASR9K):

```
snmptable -v2c -c public -M /usr/share/snmp/CISCO -m CISCO-IETF-PW-MIB -IR -Ci YOUR_ROUTER_NAME_OR_IP cpwVcTable
snmptable -v2c -c public -M /usr/share/snmp/CISCO -m CISCO-IETF-PW-MIB -IR -Ci YOUR_ROUTER_NAME_OR_IP cpwVcPerfTotalTable
```